# suggestion on implementation of visual odometry using monocular camera

Tags: camera, computer-vision, slam-algorithm

1. How to overcome scale problem in monocular visual odometery?
2. Can someone suggest me a good paper on the implementation?

Comment: maybe try some lsd ;)  http://vision.in.tum.de/research/lsdslam

Answer (score 3):

Visual-inertial fusion is the most recent approach used for monocular odometry. You need to calculate the scale between world units and meters.

You can use an Extended Kalman Filter approach or optimization as you like. Try with this paper: http://www.ee.ucr.edu/~mourikis/papers/Li2012-ICRA.pdf